# Bernoulli numbers with Boost are different from Mathematica

Tags: c++, math, boost, wolfram-mathematica, bernoulli-numbers

In the latest Boost, there is a function to compute the Bernoulli number, but I miss what it does exactly.

For example, `Mathematica`, Python `mpmath` and `www.bernoulli.org` say that:

```
BernoulliB[1] == -1/2
```

but the boost version

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bernoulli.hpp>

boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 x =  bernoulli_b2n<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100>(1);
```

returns `0.166667`

Why this difference? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All odd [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) are zero, apart of B1, which you know is -`1/2`. So, 
`boost::math::bernoulli_b2n` returns the only even (`2n`th) Bernoulli numbers.

For example, to get `B4` you need to actually pass `2`:

```
std::cout
    << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)
    << boost::math::bernoulli_b2n<double>(2) << std::endl;
```

and if you pass `1`, you get `B2`.

See docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/number_series/bernoulli_numbers.html

Of course, you can make a simple wrapper, to imitate preferred syntax<sup>1</sup>:

```
double bernoulli(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return -1.0 / 2.0; // one
    if (n % 2) return 0; // odd 
    return boost::math::bernoulli_b2n<double>(n / 2);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "B" << i << "\t" << bernoulli(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

or even a class with overloaded `operator[]` (for demanding persons ;) ):

```
class Bernoulli
{
public:
    double operator[](int n)
    {
        return bernoulli(n);
    }
};
```

or even make use of template magic and do all this checks at compile time (I will left it as an exercise for a reader ;) ).

<sub><sup>1</sup>Please note, that this exact function body is not well verified and can contains mistakes. But I hope you've got the idea of how you can make a wrapper.</sub>

Comment: I think your returns for `one` and `odd` are in the wrong order

Comment: shouldn't the return for `bernoulli(1)` be `if (n == 1) return -1.0 / 2.0;` (-1/2)?

Comment: @Baldrickk Yes. Looks like I was too fast posting this code ;) Hope it was last mistake. Anyway, the goal was to show a simple syntax imitation, not exact implementation.

Comment: @Drop of course, although correctness is always nice. I didn't see any other obvious mistakes ;)